# MySQL data storage question

Tags: mysql

How would I store the following code below `its output` in my Mysql table? How would the field be made?

```
md5(uniqid(microtime(),1))
```

example.

```
field CHAR(128) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please clarify what exactly you need to do?

Comment: How would I create my mysql table field when storing the output value from `md5(uniqid(microtime(),1))` would it look like the example `field CHAR(128) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

field CHAR(32) NOT NULL

The output of MD5() will always be 32 characters long

But of course you can save it in a binary format, in this case you should use:

field BINARY(16) NOT NULL